# How do I adjust the Y anchor of a UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

What can I replace the anchors with to raise the inputsContainerView a little higher. Currently it is centered on does not look right.

Here is the code for what I have:

```
inputsContainerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
inputsContainerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: you can change the constant from 0 to other values

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Comment: I did: inputsContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: (1)).isActive = true

Comment: But it gave me an error: Argument labels '(equalToConstant:)' do not match any available overloads

Comment: try this (PlacesSelector.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)).constant = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra parameter to adjust the anchor relative to another view. Please use autocomplete and go through the suggestions and their descriptions. Example:

```
inputsContainerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
inputsContainerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
```

Replace 10 or -10 with a value to suit your requirement. The **constant** parameter of the constraint moves the anchor relative to the mentioned anchor.

---

*Tip:* **Negative** value moves your anchor **upwards** for horizontal anchors and towards the **left** for vertical anchors. Positive values do the opposite.